# How do I validate param values (strings)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an input for time, and I only want to accept a couple of input values (6am 7am 8am 9am 10am 11am 12pm ...).

In my model, I have tried:

```ruby
VALID_TIMES = %w(6am 7am 8am 9am 10am 11am 12pm 1pm 2pm 3pm 4pm 5pm 6pm 7pm 8pm 9pm 10pm)
validates_inclusion_of :final_selected_time, :in => VALID_TIMES
```

but it isn't working. I have also tried other methods according to [the rails form validation documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), but none of them seem to work with strings. They only work with numbers.

Does anyone know a way to validate a param like `:final_selected_time` for string values?

Update:
The above code should work to validate strings.

Comment: You're right. I updated my post

Comment: With the updated code, I'm unable to reproduce "it isn't working"...when I enter "5am" for the attribute, it has an error **"Is not included in the list"**, when I enter "6am", it passes validations. Is there any other information you can give? (What does "it isn't working" look like to you, what values are you trying that are getting past, how are you putting the value in and checking that it does/does not work?)

Comment: is final_selected_time a string column in your database?

Comment: what does "not working" mean? That's the the correct syntax. You can see it in this single-file Rails app: https://gist.github.com/joshmn/3e6bcd606b623779a74206bf1e44cedc

Comment: Okay, my column was a type time, and I know that's bad practice but I didn't think that was the problem. So I just dropped my database, changed it to type string, and tested it and I get the same error......"**(0.3ms)  rollback transaction**"

Comment: never mind, my bad guys. My input still had the value of "6 am" instead of "6am". Sorry about that!

Comment: Just as a side note...your issue could have also been corrected by changing your validation instead of changing the column type.

Comment: *'My input still had the value of "6 am" instead of "6am"'* -- As with almost all questions on StackOverflow, you should try to provide a [mcve]. If you'd posted the code in your `view` then we could have *seen* the "6 am" in the input form (**Complete**), *reproduced* the problem (**Verifiable**) and explained not only the solution, but how to diagnose it yourself, within a few minutes.

Comment: ...And likewise, if you'd *shown the error message* rather than just saying "it isn't working", then the problem would have been immediately apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide us with more information. We cant help you without it. What does object actually get? Your code is ok since you changed column type to string. It checks if value equals to one of strings you specified.

Anyway you can always make the validation yourself without rails DSL (almost):

```
validate :final_selected_time_should_be_NICE

private

def final_selected_time_should_be_NICE
  return if final_selected_time ... # is ok
  errors.add(:final_selected_time, :not_appropriate)
end
```

Just change method name so it will correspond to your business logic and add condition.

Comment: OP already posted in the comments above: *'never mind, my bad guys. My input still had the value of "6 am" instead of "6am". Sorry about that!'* -- I have voted to close the question, as it was a simple typographic error that can no longer be reproduced.